# Add a style (CSS) to a custom block

Tags: blocks, 8, theming

I've created a custom Block in Drupal 8 from the UI.

Is there a way to add a custom CSS style to this custom block?
Is it possible, like in Views, to click on CSS and type it in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way to add a custom class to a block would be to override the default **block.twig.html** twig template within your theme.

You'll need to copy the above file from **/core/themes/stable/templates/block** **into your custom theme using the same directory structure**.

**  **NB** don't edit the file found in core directly!! This is bad practice and you'll lose any changes when you upgrade Drupal core. **

Clear the cache and you should now be able to edit the block template file and customize it.

Then, to load CSS, you must define an asset library. You can then load that asset library using `{{ attach_library('mytheme/special-block') }}` in your Twig template (assuming the theme is called mytheme and the asset library special-block).

**Helpful links:**

- [Working with Twig templates](https://www.drupal.org/node/2186401)
- [Template naming conventions](https://www.drupal.org/node/2354645)
- [Debugging Twig templates](https://www.drupal.org/node/1906392)
- [Adding stylesheets (CSS) and JavaScript (JS) to a Drupal 8 theme](https://www.drupal.org/theme-guide/8/assets)

Comment: To load CSS, you must define an asset library. You can then load it using `{{ attach_library('mytheme/special-block') }}` (assuming the theme is called `mytheme` and the asset library `special-block`).
See https://www.drupal.org/theme-guide/8/assets.

Comment: Apologies ignore my last comment :) thanks for the amendment

Comment: Oh I see, I didn't interpret it that way. In that case, I think you should also mention you can use `attributes.addClass('foo')` to do that. Let me add another suggestion. Then this answer will be complete, for both possible interpretations :)